# codeigniter: unable to retrieve the data using join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

Currently i have foreign key   thirdsmcontent_id value , now i want to get the value of

`thirdsubmenu_name` from `thirdmenu` table,`submenu_name` from `submenu` table,`menu_name`    from `mainmenu` table  .

Please help me to solve this problem.
 I tried below code but my model code is not correct. it is not display my data

**My Database Table Structure**

```
   1)Table: mainmenu
    ---------------
     mainmenu_id   PK(primary key)
     menu_name     ..... 

    2)Table: submenu
    -------------------
     submenu_id     PK
     mainmenu_id    FK (foreign key refrences mainmenu table)
     submenu_name   ..... 


    3)Table: thirdsubmenu
    --------------------
      thirdsubmenu_id     PK
      submenu_id          FK (foreign key refrences submenu table)
      thirdsubmenu_name     ........


    4)Table: thirdsmcontentdetails
    --------------------
      thirdsmcontent_id   PK
      thirdsubmenu_id     FK (foreign key refrences thirdsubmenu table)
      content              ......
```

**In My controller**

```
 $thirdsubmenu_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

   $data['main_menuname'] = $this->thirdsmcontentdetailsmodel->getMainMenuNameOfSubmenu($thirdsubmenu_id);
```

**In My model**

```
 //---------------------------get Main Menu Name by Menu id-----------------------------------
 function getMainMenuNameOfSubmenu($thirdsubmenu_id)
  {     
         $this->load->database();
         $query = $this->db->join('thirdsubmenu','thirdsubmenu.submenu_id = thirdsmcontentdetails.submenu_id')->get_where('thirdsubmenu',array('thirdsubmenu_id'=>$thirdsubmenu_id));  
         return $query->row('menu_name'); 
  }
```

Getting Error:

```
    A Database Error Occurred

    Error Number: 1066

    Not unique table/alias: 'thirdsubmenu'

    SELECT * FROM (`thirdsubmenu`) JOIN `thirdsubmenu` ON `thirdsubmenu`.`submenu_id` = `thirdsmcontentdetails`.`submenu_id` WHERE `thirdsubmenu_id` = '1'

    Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

    Line Number: 330
```

Comment: I think you are using wrong table in select here.

Comment: @KishorSubedi  can you post a answer for my  problem. R u nepali?

Comment: Yes I am. OK i will post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining both `FROM` and `JOIN` as `thirdsubmenu` that isn't possible and makes no sense.
Either use:

```
$this->db->join('thirdsubmenu','thirdsubmenu.submenu_id = thirdsmcontentdetails.submenu_id');
$query = $this->db->get_where('thirdsmcontentdetails',array('thirdsubmenu_id'=>$thirdsubmenu_id));
```

Or:

```
$this->db->from('thirdsmcontentdetails');
$this->db->join('thirdsubmenu','thirdsubmenu.submenu_id = thirdsmcontentdetails.submenu_id')
$this->db->where(array('thirdsubmenu_id'=>$thirdsubmenu_id));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Have a look at the [`CI documentation`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) to see how you have to define a join.